# Bind Custom Object Type in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin Forms at the moment and I'm impressed by the MVVM concept and I try to use bindings as recommended. If I have a textfield that I want to display some text in I will bind that textfield to a string. The thing is though that I would like to bind this to a custom object-type instead. Let's say that it represents order id. The order id will be displayed as a string of a special format. Let's say it is always 10 characters, the 2 first are always country code, the rest are individual. This would be nice to have contained in an object that can validate it self. Is there any way that I can bind this custom object? How do I control how it is represented in the view? Should I use ToString()? This would be a bit unflexible since I would perhaps like to display this a bit differently in different context.

Any feedback would be helpful(except for the validation in itself for the order, I know how to do that).

Comment: If you could post the code you are working with, it might help to suggest a solution. Have you tried binding your text field to the custom object's property? Such as `<Entry Text="{Binding CustomObject.Id}"/>` or `label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "CustomObject.Id");`

Comment: That's it! Didn't know I could write CustomObject.Id in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried binding your text field to the custom object's property? Such as `<Entry Text="{Binding CustomObject.Id}"/>` or `label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "CustomObject.Id");`

Answer (score 0):

```
Label label = new Label();
// myObject is your custom object
label.BindingContext = myObject;
// MyPropertyName is some public property on your object you want to display
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MyPropertyName");
```